# Send multidimensional Array to controller MVC 4

Tags: arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, multidimensional-array

i have a problem sending a multidimensional array to my controller. I have a table with 30 rows, this rows are created in a for loop.

The thing is i create a multidimensional array for the 5 elements inside of one row of my table.

**function**

```
 $.fn.RealizarCalculo = function (count) {

    var admin = $("#AdminSimple" + count).val();
    var fondo = $("#FondosSimple" + count + " option:selected").text();
    var secId = $("#FondosSimple" + count).val();
    var monto = $("#MontoSimple" + count).val();
    var porcentaje = $("#PorSimple" + count).val();
    var list = new Array();

    if (admin != "" && secId != "" && monto != "" && porcentaje != "") 
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) 
        {
            var admin = $("#AdminSimple" + i).val();
            var fondo = $("#FondosSimple" + i + " option:selected").text();
            var secId = $("#FondosSimple" + i).val();
            var monto = $("#MontoSimple" + i).val();
            var porcentaje = $("#PorSimple" + i).val();

            list[i] = [{ administrador: admin, fondoCartera: fondo, sec: secId, montoCartera: monto, porcentajeC: porcentaje}];

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "Simu/RealizarSimulacion",
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ lista:list }),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function () {
            alert("sucess");
        });

    }
   };
```

How i receive this array i created?

i have tried but is not working, is just receive a list of objects.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult RealizarSimulacion(Array lista)
        {

            return View("Simulador");
        }
```

Thanks for help, and sorry for my English, i'm chilean.

Comment: Related: You're receiving a list of objects because that's what you've declared that method to receive.

Comment: Yes, but i can't get the attributes of the objects, like administrador, fondoCartera, etc.

Comment: That's because `object` has no such properties. I've not actually done this myself (POSTing json like this), so I'm not sure exactly what the correct things would be to use, but I wonder if a `list<dynamic>` would work, or maybe there's another data structure..

Comment: It doesn't work, the array comes like this: [1]"[object Object]" when you left the mouse over the variable.

Comment: What is the point of a multi-dimensional array here - the inner array only contains one object! It could be just `list.push({ administrador: admin, fondoCartera: fondo, sec: secId, montoCartera: monto, porcentajeC: porcentaje});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you do not (and should not) be creating a multi-dimensional array. Its an array of objects. Second you cant post back to `Array` (array of what? and `Array` is an abstract class!)

Create an object with the properties you are posting (adjust property types to suit)

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string administrador { get; set; }
  public string fondoCartera { get; set; }
  public string sec{ get; set; }
  public string montoCartera{ get; set; }
  public string porcentajeC { get; set; }
}
```

and adjust the script

```
$.fn.RealizarCalculo = function (count) {
  var admin = $("#AdminSimple" + count).val();
  ....
  var list = new Array();

  if (admin != "" && secId != "" && monto != "" && porcentaje != "") {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
      var admin = $("#AdminSimple" + i).val();
      list.push({ administrador: admin, fondoCartera: fondo, sec: secId, montoCartera: monto, porcentajeC: porcentaje});
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("RealizarSimulacion", "Simu")', // dont hardcode url's!
      type: "POST",
      traditional: true,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({ lista: list }),
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function () {
      alert("success");
    });
  }
};
```

and the controller method (note you return a view, but you ajax function expects JSON (`dataType: 'json'`) and you don't do anything with the returned value anyway!)

```
public ActionResult RealizarSimulacion(MyClass[] lista) // or List<MyClass> lista
{
  return View("Simulador"); // this makes no sense
}
```

It hard to understand what this code is doing, but if you really do have controls with `id=adminSimple1"`, `id=adminSimple2"` etc. you need to stop coding and start learning some basics of MVC including how to use view models and how to render controls in a view using strongly typed html helpers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i know about helpers, but i couldn't find a way to implement them for i wanted to do. I'm working in an MVC aplication, but the proyect is one of the 8 proyects(is an n-layer solution), so to acces a dto or structures is not easy, plus, i'm just learning MVC about a month, so, you are right, i have to study more MVC. Thanks for your help again.