# posting json data through ajax in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var car = [{ "name": "Audi", "Model": "A6", "color": "White", "type": "sedan", "date": "12/4/2014", "range": "20" },
   { "name": "Honda", "Model": "City", "color": "Black", "type": "sedan", "date": "12/12/2014", "range": "27" },
   { "name": "Mahindra", "Model": "Scorpio", "color": "Black", "type": "SUV", "date": "9/12/2014", "range": "29" },
   { "name": "Benz", "Model": "320D", "color": "Red", "type": "sedan", "date": "7/12/2014", "range": "37" },
   { "name": "hyundai", "Model": "Accent", "color": "Metal", "type": "sedan", "date": "11/12/2014", "range": "31" },
   { "name": "Skoda", "Model": "Rapid", "color": "Grey", "type": "sedan", "date": "12/1/2014", "range": "65" }];


    var rec = JSON.stringify(car);

$(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "home/json",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {"data":"car"},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
}});});
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult json(string data) 
{
  return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Can any one help me to post data to controller and get it back to data in ajax.

Comment: Why are you posting back to a `string`? Do you have a model that this should be binding to?

Comment: i want my json data to post to the controller and return it to my grid

Comment: Whats the point of passing this to a controller and returning exactly the same thing? And do you have a model that this should be binding to?

Comment: data: {"data":"car"}  here car is hard coded,  this should be data: {"data":car}

Comment: $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                        dataSource: data,
                        allowSorting: true,});

Comment: this is my grid and i want the posted data as source for this grid

Comment: i changed that too({"data":car}), but im not getting my json posted to my controller.It just posting the name car to the controller

Comment: @koushikr, Your posting back a collection of objects (incorrectly - but that's easy to fix) so you need to bind to a collection of objects (not a string). But (again), what is the point of sending it to the server and returning it unchanged? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i got a task to post json data through ajax and get it back from server and make it as a datasource for the grid.but i am not clear with concepts of ajax json posting in mvc.

Comment: If you want to know how to pass `car` to a server then [refer to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281001/send-multidimensional-array-to-controller-mvc-4/27284554#27284554), but whats the point. Just pass `car` to the grid `$("#Grid").ejGrid({ dataSource: car, allowSorting: true,});` If you don't know what your trying to do, how can anyone else.

Comment: sorry dont get tensed.This is assigned to me to just get an idea about how ajax is posting and getting back the data.Instead of directly giving the source for grid, i have to put the data returned to the ajax success function

Comment: Grid is a client side control, data comes from the server. You make a call to controller method, it returns the data that your can load in your grid. You are attempting to do something which is not logical. Stephen pointed that in detail in his comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a class in your MVC application in which to hold your data. Notice how the property names match those in your JSON data. You can use a different property for date but for now I've left this as a string.

```
public class Car

{

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Model { get; set; }

    public String Color { get; set; }

    public String Type { get; set; }

    public String Date { get; set; }

    public int Range { get; set; }

}
```

Then amend your controller to use this new class. Notice how this is binding to a collection of Car which supports the multiple datasets youre sending.

```
public ActionResult json(Car[] data) 
{
  return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You also need to stringify the response otherwise you wont be able to output it in the message box. Update your script to be the following.

```
$("#btn").on( "click", function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("json")",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "data": car },
            success: function (data) {


                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want me to expand on anything.

**UPDATE - Without Car class (Mapping to String)**

Action

```
public ActionResult json(string data)
{

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Script - Pass over rec instead of car

```
var rec = JSON.stringify(car);

$("#btn").on( "click", function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("json")",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "data": rec },
            success: function (data) {


                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.what is the purpose of creating class for my data?Can i give it like i did previously(simple json format)?what the code (Car[] data) will do?

Comment: The point of creating a Car class is that it gives you a structure for your data. You could post the whole thing to a string but then the data becomes meaninglyless.

Comment: @koushikr I've updated my answer to show how you can bind to a string instead of a custom class

Comment: public ActionResult json(string data)
{

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}        it is not returning me Json objects.I am using JSON.parse(data); to convert the receiving string to objects.  Hence what is the use of return Json(data,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);

Comment: It serializes the specified object (In this case data) to JSON format. I've tested the code I posted and it does indeed return JSON. You dont need to covert the response to JSON as AJAX already takes care of this. It clever enough to know what datatype it is receiving.